# zend framework cannot find helper view file. Get 'Plugin by name was not found' error

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view

I am trying to simply use a custom view helper that is located in `/library/my/view/helpers/friends.php`

I have this in the `application.ini`:

`resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = "/my/view/helpers"`

This is the helper class:

```
class My_View_Helper_Friends extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
    public function friends() {
        $str = "hello world";
        return $str;
    }
}
```

This is in the view file:

```
<?php echo $this->friends(); ?>
```

I get an error on this line saying it can't find the plugin in a path that it is already in.

The error:

> Plugin by name 'Friends' was not found in the registry; used paths:
>   My_View_Helper_: /My/View/Helpers/ Zend_View_Helper_:
>   Zend/View/Helper/;C:/http/xampplite/htdocs/zf-tutorial/application/views\helpers/

Looks like its using the right path and the file is there. I don't understand why it can't find it?

Comment: I've always had to use `$this->helper()` to make it work. Also my view  helpers are all `Zend_View_Helper_MyHelper` (maybe try a rename) although I don't put them in the library, I keep them in `/views/helpers` to keep things simple. You didn't mention if you added the `autoloaderNamespaces[] = MY_` to your application.ini. Not sure if that would be a factor or not.

Comment: @RockyFord It may be that you always have to use `$this->helper()` because you are naming your classes `Zend_View_Helper_XXX` (if I read that correctly).  Only classes officially belonging to ZF should be prefixed with `Zend_` or `ZendX_` (See [ZF Naming Conventions](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html)).  It might have to do with the autoloader looking in the Zend directories for your helper classes.

Comment: @drew010 I should said `$this->MyHelper()` prefixing with `Zend_View_Helper_XXX` is the default. So I don't have to register a new helper path. They are stored in any of my `/views/helpers` directories. Someday I'll put them all in one place, when I cleanup the application. Also the question has been cleaned up since I posted, so my post makes less sense :)

Comment: I have also tried putting the Friends helper in /application/views/helpers/ and still get the same error. I renamed the class to Zend_View_Helper_Friends. Do I have to include anything in the helper file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that the incorrect path is being used.

> ...used paths: My_View_Helper_: /My/View/Helpers/

Note how the path is `/My/View/Helpers`.  It is using an absolute path.  The other issue is that the folder should be named `Helper` instead of `helpers`.

Then change the config line in your `application.ini` to this:

```
resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/my/view/helper"
```

and make sure your class is called `My_View_Helper_Friends` and the file is named `Friends.php`.  Case matters.  The directory should really be called `My/View/Helper` with caps.

**EDIT:**  Assuming `library` is in your `include_path`, you could also use the line:

```
resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = "My/View/Helper"
```

Notice how it doesn't have the leading `/`.  This will search all locations in your `include_path` for a folder `My/View/Helper`.

Comment: I did exactly as you recommended for the first option. Added that path constant, capitalized my dir names and made sure the helper class name is right. Now I get this error: Plugin by name 'Friends' was not found in the registry; used paths: My_View_Helper_: C:\http\xampplite\htdocs\zf-tutorial\application../library/my/view/helper/ Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/;C:/http/xampplite/htdocs/zf-tutorial/application/views\helpers/

Comment: I am using windows 7. Notice that application constant is spitting out back slashes and the rest of the path is forward slashes. I think that is the problem. Looks like all the paths in the application.ini that use that constant is mix forward and backward slashes.

Comment: Why is the path in appliation.ini all lowercase if the actual dir names is capital case? I am not concerned about naming convention at this point. Just what works.

Comment: In the case of the first application.ini line I gave you, I left off a slash.  It should be `resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library/my/view/helper"` which is now reflected in the post.  See if that works for you.  The path is still incorrect given my original example which resulted in `C:\http\xampplite\htdocs\zf-tutorial\application../library/my/view/helper/`

Comment: Now I get this error: Plugin by name 'Friends' was not found in the registry; used paths: My_View_Helper_: C:\http\xampplite\htdocs\zf-tutorial\application/../library/my/view/helper/ Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/;C:/http/xampplite/htdocs/zf-tutorial/application/views\helpers/.  That path looks strange with forward and backward slashes. How does that work? I read somewhere about adding 'My_' to the autoloader. Tried autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My_" in the .ini and that didn't work either.

Comment: The mixed slashes shouldn't be a problem generally.  It does appear to be looking for classes named `My_View_Helper_XXX` in `C:\http\xampplite\htdocs\zf-tutorial\application/../library/my/view/helper/`  Can you confirm if that is the correct path to the library folder and then your view helpers?  Maybe try correcting the case so it says `C:\http\xampplite\htdocs\zf-tutorial\application/../library/My/View/Helper/` if possible.

Comment: If not, try just using this line instead: `resources.view.helperPath.My_View_Helper = "My/View/Helper"`

Comment: Does the ../ mean go up one dir from application dir? Tried both methods and still get the error. The .ini file even has this: includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

Comment: @drew010 Was using a plain text editor and failed to notice no open <?php tag in the Friends class file. That was it. Very stupid of me. Sorry for all of this.